# Can you pass-by-reference in R?

Tags: r, oop, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Can you pass by reference with "R" ?
for example, in the following code:

```
setClass("MyClass",
    representation(
    name="character"
    ))


instance1 <-new("MyClass",name="Hello1")
instance2 <-new("MyClass",name="Hello2")

array = c(instance1,instance2)

instance1
array

instance1@name="World!"

instance1
array
```

the output is

```
> instance1
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "World!"

> array
[[1]]
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "Hello1"


[[2]]
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "Hello2"
```

but I wish it was

```
> instance1
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "World!"

> array
[[1]]
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "World!"


[[2]]
An object of class “MyClass”
Slot "name":
[1] "Hello2"
```

is it possible ?

Comment: I really wonder why they came up with such an unusual implementation.

Comment: Objects or primitives? S3, S4 or R6? Using environments or otherwise? R 1.x, 2.x or 3.x? The answers here span 2010-15 and they disagree with each other. This question is an unholy mess and needs cleaning up. Also, it's useful when saying 'Yes/No' to cite releases or dates: e.g. 'as of R 3.0 / 2013'. To future-proof the answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**No**.

Objects in assignment statements are immutable. R will copy the object not *just* the reference.

```
> v = matrix(1:12, nrow=4)
> v
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
     [1,]    1    5    9
     [2,]    2    6   10
     [3,]    3    7   11
     [4,]    4    8   12
> v1 = v
> v1[,1]     # fetch the first column 
     [1] 1 2 3 4
```

(*proviso*: the statement above is true for R *primitives*, e.g., vectors, matrices), and also for *functions*; I cannot say for certain whether it's true for *all* R objects--just most of them, as well as the vast majority of the ones most often used.)

If you don't like this behavior you can opt out of it with the help from an R Package. E.g., there is an R Package called **R.oo** that allows you to mimic pass-by-reference behavior; R.oo is available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

Comment: See also the `mutatr` and `proto` packages.

Comment: `mutatr` seems unsupported and undocumented.

Comment: @doug can you pass by reference using a `.Call` wrapper of a C++?

Comment: I find this "No." rather, well, *bold*, since many packages seem to allow passage by reference,  [as well as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300707/1267815) `Rcpp` interface with C/C++.

Answer (score 54):

Note that if you hope to use pass-by-reference simply to avoid the performance implications of copying an object that isn't modified (as is common in other languages with constant references), R does this automatically:

```
n <- 10^7
bigdf <- data.frame( x=runif(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rt(n,5) )
myfunc <- function(dat) invisible(with( dat, x^2+mean(y)+sqrt(exp(z)) ))
myfunc2 <- function(dat) {
    x <- with( dat, x^2+mean(y)+sqrt(exp(z)) )
    invisible(x)
}
myfunc3 <- function(dat) {
    dat[1,1] <- 0
    invisible( with( dat, x^2+mean(y)+sqrt(exp(z)) ) )
}
tracemem(bigdf)
> myfunc(bigdf)
> # nothing copied
> myfunc2(bigdf)
> # nothing copied!
> myfunc3(bigdf)
tracemem[0x6e430228 -> 0x6b75fca0]: myfunc3 
tracemem[0x6b75fca0 -> 0x6e4306f0]: [<-.data.frame [<- myfunc3 
tracemem[0x6e4306f0 -> 0x6e4304f8]: [<-.data.frame [<- myfunc3 
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(myfunc(bigdf), myfunc2(bigdf), myfunc3(bigdf), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
1 myfunc2(bigdf)  617.8176  641.7673  644.3764  683.6099  698.1078
2 myfunc3(bigdf) 1052.1128 1134.0822 1196.2832 1202.5492 1206.5925
3  myfunc(bigdf)  598.9407  622.9457  627.9598  642.2727  654.8786
```

Comment: Very helpful to know!  I'd also add that this appears to apply ONLY to data.frames.  Matrices/Arrays are always pass-by-value, as I just learned after a few hours of scratching at Rprof output.

Comment: re-running this on my laptop now: all times are the same now (and half those of five years ago)

Comment: The tracemem part need to be explained a little

Comment: @AndrewChristianson IIUC, this is the current behavior, also for `matrix`, `array` and `tibble`. Has the behavior changed since you posted your comment, or am I wrong?

Comment: @OrenMilman oh gosh, probably?  that comment is from quite a few years ago, and was probably made in reference to R 2.15 / 2.14, which I was using at the time.

Answer (score 29):

As several have pointed out before, this can be done via using objects of class `environment`. There exists a formal approach building upon the use of `environment`s. It's called *Reference Classes* and makes things really easy for you. Check `?setRefClass` for the main entry help page. It also describes how to use formal methods with Reference Classes.

### Example

```
setRefClass("MyClass",
    fields=list(
        name="character"
    )
)

instance1 <- new("MyClass",name="Hello1")
instance2 <- new("MyClass",name="Hello2")

array = c(instance1,instance2)

instance1$name <- "World!"
```

### Output

```
> instance1
Reference class object of class "MyClass"
Field "name":
[1] "World!"

> array
[[1]]
Reference class object of class "MyClass"
Field "name":
[1] "World!"

[[2]]
Reference class object of class "MyClass"
Field "name":
[1] "Hello2"
```

Answer (score 26):

Pass-by-reference is possible for `environment`s. To use them, basically whenever you create an object you would need to create an environment slot as well. But I think that it is cumbersome. Have a look at 
[Pass by reference for S4.](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-January/051899.html) and [Pointers and passing by reference in R](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Pointers_passing_reference_.html)

Comment: The links work now. These days should list the S4 one ahead of S3.

Answer (score 6):

R does have a library now that allows you to do OOP using references. See [ReferenceClasses](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/refClass.html) which is part of the methods package.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the **R.oo** package emulates the pass-by-reference behaviour by using environments.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here that actually *pass* your object by reference (`environment` objects and Reference Classes), if you're purely interested in call-by-reference for syntactic convenience (i.e. you don't mind your data copied inside), you could emulate that by assigning the final value back to the outside variable while returning:

```
byRef <- function(..., envir=parent.frame(), inherits=TRUE) {
  cl <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  cl[c(1, match(c("envir", "inherits"), names(cl), 0L))] <- NULL
  for (x in as.list(cl)) {
    s <- substitute(x)
    sx <- do.call(substitute, list(s), envir=envir)
    dx <- deparse(sx)
    expr <- substitute(assign(dx, s, envir=parent.frame(), inherits=inherits))
    do.call(on.exit, list(expr, add=TRUE), envir=envir)
  }
}
```

Then we can declare "call-by-reference" arguments:

```
f <- function(z1, z2, z3) {
  byRef(z1, z3)

  z1 <- z1 + 1
  z2 <- z2 + 2
  z3 <- z3 + 3

  c(z1, z2, z3)
}

x1 <- 10
x2 <- 20
x3 <- 30

# Values inside:
print(f(x1, x2, x3))
# [1] 11 22 33

# Values outside:
print(c(x1, x2, x3))
# [1] 11 20 33
```

Note that if you access the "by-reference" variables by their outside names (`x1`, `x3`)  anywhere inside the function, you'll get their yet-unmodified values from the outside. Also, this implementation only handles simple variable names as arguments, so indexed arguments such as `f(x[1], ...)` will not work (though you could probably implement that with a bit more involved expression manipulation to sidestep the limited `assign`).

Answer (score 2):

On top of the other suggestions, you can also write C/C++ functions taking their arguments by reference and working *in-place*, and call them directly in R thanks to `Rcpp` (among others).
See in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300707/1267815).