# Global variable in a package - which approach is more recommended?

Tags: r, package

I do understand that generally global variables are evil and I should avoid them, but if my package does need to have a global variable, which of these two approaches are better?  And are there any other recommended approaches?

1. Using an environment visible to the package

   ```
   pkgEnv <- new.env()  
   pkgEnv$sessionId <- "xyz123"
   ```
2. Using `options`

   ```
   options("pkgEnv.sessionId" = "xyz123")
   ```

I know there are some other threads that ask about how to achieve global variables, but I haven't seen a discussion on which one is recommended

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some packages use hidden variables (variables that begin with a `.`), like `.Random.seed` and `.Last.value` do in base R. In your package you could do

```
e <- new.env()
assign(".sessionId", "xyz123", envir = e)
ls(e)
# character(0)
ls(e, all = TRUE)
# [1] ".sessionId"
```

But in your package you don't need to assign `e`. You can use a `.onLoad()` hook to assign the variable upon loading the package.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    assign(".sessionId", "xyz123", envir = parent.env(environment()))
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598242/global-variables-in-packages-in-r) and its answers for some good explanation on package variables.

Comment: Some comments, via your link, would suggest your first approach with `e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())` is the best approach. But this seems to be at odds with your second approach where you set `envir = parent.env(environment())`? I've tried both. Both work. But this stuff is way over my head. Are the two approaches basically the same or would I be more likely to run into fussy behavior down the road with one of these approaches?

Answer (score 3):

When most people say you should avoid 'global' variables, they mean you should not assign to the global environment (`.GlobalEnv`,`GlobalEnv`, or `as.environment(1)`) or that you should not pass information between internal functions by any method other than passing such data as the arguments of a function call.

Caching is another matter entirely.  I often caching results that I don't want to re-calculate (memoization) or re-query.  A pattern I use a lot in packages is the following:

```
myFunction <- local({

    cache <- list() # or numeric(0) or whatever

    function(x,y,z){ 

        # calculate the index of the answer 
        # (most of the time this is a trivial calculation, often the identity function)
        indx = answerIndex(x,y,z)

        # check if the answer is stored in the cache
        if(indx %in% names(cacheList))
            # if so, return the answer
            return(cacheList[indx])

        [otherwise, do lots of calculations or data queries]

        # store the answer
        cahceList[indx] <<- answer

        return(answer)
    }

})
```

The call to `local` creates a new environment where I can store results using the scoping assignment operator `<<-` without having to worry about the fact that the package was already sealed, and the last expression (the function definition) is returned as the value of the call to `local()` and is bound to the name `myFunction`.