# How to make variable available to namespace at loading time

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

In one of my packages I use the `.onAttach` hook to run some R code and then use `assign` to make the value available as one of the package variables. I do it because `variable` depends on the content of some file, which can change between one session and the other. The code I use is like:

```
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
   variable <- some_function()
   assign("variable", variable, envir = as.environment("package:MyRPackage"))
}
```

When I attach the package with `library(MyRpackage)` I can use `variable`.

However it is not possible to do something like `MyRPackage::variable` (unless I have already attached the package with `library(MyRpackage)`.

I know this is because I should put that code in the `.onLoad` hook, however I can't make the assignment so that it works.

I have tried

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
   variable <- some_function()
   assign("variable", variable, envir = as.environment("namesoace:MyRPackage"))
}
```

and

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
   variable <- some_function()
   assign("variable", variable, envir = asNamespace("MyRPackage"))
}
```

but both of them fail with some error when I run `MyRPackage:::variable` without using `library` to attach the package.

What is the correct to do the assignment in the .onLoad hook?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to recompute variable each time during loading?

Comment: can you export `some_function` so that you can call `MyRPackage::some_function()`?

Comment: @Dason it has to read data from a file

Comment: @lucacerone is that file going to be changing every session or something?

Comment: yes Dason, it can change between one session and the other

Comment: I'm not sure you can use `MyRPackage:::variable` without loading the package before because the `variable` is assigned only when you actually load the package. Something I don't understand?

Comment: F. Privé I want to load the package.. I don't want to necessarily attach it.. for all the other exported functions you can do pkg::function, but for the one created in .onLoad I didn't manage to find a way

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248227/8386140) to a related question, you can change your `.onLoad()` function like so:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    variable <- some_function()
    assign("variable", variable, envir = parent.env(environment()))
}
```

Then you can access `variable` without attaching the package using `MyRPackage:::variable`. I don't know what you do with `some_function()`, so I tried the following with a dummy package:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    variable <- 42
    assign("variable", variable, envir = parent.env(environment()))
}
```

And in a fresh R session the result was

```
> MyRPackage:::variable
[1] 42
```

#### Further explanation

From Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html):

> There are four special environments:
>
> ...
>
> - The environment() is the current environment.
>
> ...
>
> You can list the bindings in the environment’s frame with ls() and
>   see its parent with parent.env().

So, if we modify the `.onLoad()` function further, we can see this in action:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    print(environment()) # For demonstration purposes only;
    print(parent.env(environment())) # Don't really do this.
    variable <- 42
    assign("variable", variable, envir = parent.env(environment()))
}
```

Then starting an R session results in

```
<environment: 0x483da88>
<environment: namespace:MyRPackage>
```

being printed to the console at the start of the session. This allows you to assign `variable` in the environment `namespace:MyRPackage` even though trying `assign("variable", variable, envir = namespace:MyRPackage)` would result in the error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MyRPackage’:
>
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'MyRPackage', details:
>
> call: get(name, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE)
>
> error: object 'namespace' not found

when installing the package.

Comment: thanks duckymar, let me make a couple of tests and I'll let you know whether it worked or not

Comment: it worked perfectly thanks :) could you improve just slightly the answer by explaining briefly what the parent.env( environment()) is actually doing?

Comment: @lucacerone I will edit later today to add more detail

Comment: @lucacerone Some further explanation is added.

Answer (score 5):

There are essentially three ways, from easiest to most complex:

1. via direct assignment: `ns$name = value`
2. via `assign(…, envir = topenv())`
3. via `assignInMyNamespace(…)`

Although option 3 seems to be [quite widespread](https://github.com/search?q=assignInMyNamespace+-path%3A*.Rd+language%3AR&type=code), it requires writing more code, in multiple places, because you’ll first need to create a variable before you can overwrite it via `assignInMyNamespace()`:

```r
myvar = NULL

.onLoad = function (libname, pkgname) {
    assignInMyNamespace('myvar', value)
}
```

Failure to pre-declare the variable will lead to an error.

By contrast, `assign` is perfectly capable of creating a new variable which hasn’t been declared before. We just have to tell R into which environment to assign the variable, and the function [`topenv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/ns-topenv.html) provides this.

```r
.onLoad = function (libname, pkgname) {
    assign('myvar', value, envir = topenv())
}
```

And of course we don’t need `assign()` (or `assignInMyNamespace()`) if we define a namespace object and subset-assign into it:

```r
.onLoad = function (libname, pkgname) {
    ns = topenv()
    ns$myvar = value
}
```

For my own code I am gravitating towards that option.

Comment: R doc says: `assignInNamespace` should not be used in final code, and will in future throw an error if called from a package. Already certain uses are disallowed. For now, the option 1 is not used by almost all the packages.

Comment: @LiangZhang `assignInMyNamespace` ≠ `assignInNamespace`! Anyway, I personally don’t recommend using that option for the reasons mentioned in my answer, despite its relatively widespread usage. I always use the direct assignment.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry to ignore that `My` word! Thank you very much. I love your `ns$name = value` method.

Comment: By the way, it is possibly misleading in the doc of `memoise::memoise()`: it adds example with statement of `fun <<- memoise::memoise(fun)`. Maybe it could be corrected as your method here.