# Workaround for clusterExport issue when using C++ compiled functions / use .onLoad in R?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a question re: the issue that Rcpp modules are not easily exported as regular R objects. In particular, my code is object-oriented and uses an instance of a class exported to R. The issue has been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518387/using-rcpp-functions-inside-of-rs-parapply-functions-from-the-parallel-package).

A possible workaround is [to load a few things into the environment upon loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056642/how-to-make-variable-available-to-namespace-at-loading-time/67664852#67664852) but I don't quite understand how to hold back my `zzz.R` which gets executed prematurely (build vs. load time) which results in an error because the modules called in zzz.R only become available AFTER compilation and installation.

Comment: I have the feeling we answered this via a number of related questions.  Can you do search?

Comment: I have but only saw this suggested conceptually and no actual answer, by Roman Francois on an old thread. Can you or someone give a hint of how to properly include the zzz.R or maybe even work out how to give proper citizenship to Rcpp-exported objects?

Comment: The short answer is that your best bet, by far, is to wrap your code into a package and have each worker node load the package ensuring proper local instantation.  Rcpp Modules is R glue code around compiler code loaded in a 'random' and 'hidden' RAM location on your server and there is no mechanism to send it to nodes, just as there isn't really for persisting modules across sessions.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for that. Do you have a reference for making .onLoad work properly? I already have it wrapped in a package because it's using custom headers. I shall make this available for the gallery shortly as it is a good example of using classes and modules.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem, and hence question is, but I can assure you that a number of (public, on CRAN) packages use Rcpp Modules just fine so I can only urge you to maybe study one or two of those to identify what you may be doing wrong.  Rcpp Modules code has not changed in a while, and generally does not require `zzz.R` or `.onLoad()` so the problem may be yours alone. Sorry!

Comment: My issue is that I need to construct an object from my C++ class, and loading the package does not allow that. When I ask my zzz.R/.onLoad to execute "MyClass myobj", devtools::document() etc. complain that that MyClass is not found, so I get a catch22. I am thinking of just wrapping construction of my object in a C-style function and returning a function pointer or something like that.

Comment: Well all we say is that `loadModules()` be placed in _any_ file in `R/`.  So maybe make it `zzz.R` or `init.R` and call it first, then instantiate. Should work.  Or, if you need something special, use something else.  Modules are just one way, we often also use `Rcpp::XPtr` to instantiate ourself.

Comment: I think Rcpp::XPtr is the way to go. I shall try and instatiate at the cpp level and return an XPtr using https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/ if that is what you mean?

Comment: I agree. You get more control.  I keep forgetting in which package I did this (maybe it was once at work...) but I set up a basic class, and then some simple helper functions to a) instantiate and hook to a (global) pointer, b) access setter and gettres and c) and unwind function to release.  Basically what Modules gives you, but more manually for finer control.