# getwd() returns non-existent directory in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-package, working-directory

I have the following Shiny package:

`DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: mypackage
Version: 0.0.1
Depends: shiny
```

`R/mypackage.R`:

```r
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(getwd())
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
```

To install and run, I do

```sh
R -q -e "devtools::install(); shiny::runApp(shinyApp(mypackage:::ui, mypackage:::server))"
```

And when I do this, my app outputs

```
/tmp/RtmpC1viCa/R.INSTALL6931e8be933/mypackage
```

which does not exist.

Why is that, and how I improve that? I have seen that `getwd()` may not actually return the users working directory - but why is it returning a non-existent one?

Comment: To see the problem, it helps to just paste `shiny::fluidPage(getwd())` into the R console: that gives `<div class="container-fluid">C:/Users/bers</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a Shiny app, `getwd()` refers to the application directory.

However, since you are creating a package, you need to be aware of, and careful about, where/when code is executed.

Code at file scope inside a package is executed *at installation time*. And installation of R packages happens inside a temporary directory to isolate it. In fact, `R CMD check` will warn you about this.

If you need the value of `getwd()` (as well as other path specific functions such as `system.file`), you *mustn’t* call it at file scope.

The solution is to use the [`.onLoad` package hook](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/userhooks.html). In your case, [you need to create and assign the *entire* UI at package load time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664852/1968):

```
.onLoad <- function (libname, pkgname) {
    assign(
        'ui',
        shiny::fluidPage(getwd()),
        topenv()
    )

}
```

If you dislike using `assign`, `$<-` also works:

```
.onLoad <- function (libname, pkgname) {
    topenv()$ui <- shiny::fluidPage(getwd()),
}
```

But alternatively you could also create a *function* that returns the UI:

```
ui <- function () {
    shiny::fluidPage(getwd())
}
```

And run it via

```
shiny::runApp(shinyApp(mypackage:::ui(), mypackage:::server))
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the explanation! Of course, my real app has a much greater depth of functions calling one another. It's amazing that all this (UI) code was run only once during installation, and still worked perfectly until I came across the issue with the working directory.

Comment: As you explained, I cannot access the "real" working directory anyway. Assuming that is true, what if I simply left everything as is - are there any downsides to be expected? Is the run-code-at-install-time variant maybe even faster?

Comment: @bers Sure, running code at installation will potentially make package loading faster. But be sure to benchmark this: it’s quite likely not a substantial improvement. (Aside: the fact that Shiny changes the user’s working directory is extremely annoying, and arguably a bug. If you want to work around this, you’ll need to store the value of `getwd()` *before* creating the Shiny application, i.e. before calling `shiny::runApp`.)

Comment: I think the biggest argument against running code at installation is that future versions of dependencies will not be taken into account, until `mypackage` itself is reinstalled. I will go for `ui()` now - thanks :)