# Package environment manipulation and submitting to CRAN

Tags: r, package, rstudio, cran

I have [built a package](https://rjake.github.io/shinysim/) for shiny that allows the user to interact with reactive objects in their global environment. I think it's a game changer for troubleshooting. However, I know that CRAN will reject this due to the manipulation of the global environment. I see answers directing users to create a new environment but I don't see how to access the objects of that environment in the environment pane, I just see the environment name.

If I run something like this from this example: 
[Global variable in a package - which approach is more recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246952/global-variable-in-a-package-which-approach-is-more-recommended)

```
e <- new.env()
assign("a", "xyz123", envir = e)
e$b <- 1
```

I see this, and clicking on `e` will call `View(e)`

[image]

I want `e` to be something the user can see on the right-hand side like it is when the user is in their global environment or when debugging a function:

[image]

A similar question was asked here but did not address changing how the user sees objects in the IDE:

[CRAN policy on use of global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604073/cran-policy-on-use-of-global-variables)

This stuff is new territory so I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: You shouldn't tamper with the global environment because you don't know what's in it. Worst case, when you do `assign("e", obj, globalenv())`, you overwrite an existing object `e` that the user created previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `attach(e)`, then `e` will be available to be chosen in the environment pane.  You should pair this with `detach(e)` so that you don't permanently mess up the user's search list.

If the user chooses to look at `e` when it is attached, it won't disappear when it is detached, but it won't be available to select again after being detached if the user views a different environment.

I don't know if there's an RStudio API way to automatically select it.

Edited to add:  The `attach()` function creates a new environment copying the value of `e` at the time of attaching.  That's probably not what you want.  There is a way to get a live one though:

```
attach(NULL, name = "Viewable")
e <- as.environment("Viewable")

# Now somehow get the user to view it in the Environment pane

# Clean up the search list
detach("Viewable")
```

You then have a live environment, things like

```
e$a <- 123
```

will show up there.

Comment: Ok, one step closer. That shows up in the pane but is says "Empty Environment" in that pane when I run the code above even though `ls(envir = e)` shows values.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution to that problem.