# Access R objects created in function

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I'm trying to put [something](https://rjake.github.io/shinyobjects/) on CRAN that allows the user to manipulate reactive shiny objects by making an analogous static object on the search path. I know I cannot write to the global environment (what it currently does) but I'm not sure how to let the objects persist once the function is executed.

```r
store_it <- function() {
  env <- new.env()
  assign("x", runif(10), env)
  assign("iris_df", head(iris), env)
  # View(env)
  env
}

# how I want to use it, doesn't work
store_it() # <environment: 0x0000012bd8959cb0>
x          # Error: object 'x' not found
iris_df    # Error: object 'iris_df' not found

# works
e <- attach(store_it())

x
iris_df
```

It does what I want but I don't like that it keeps adding environments to the search path:

```r
e <- attach(store_it())
# The following objects are masked from store_it() (pos = 3):
#   iris_df, x

e <- attach(store_it())
# The following objects are masked from store_it() (pos = 4):
#   iris_df, x

e <- attach(store_it())
# The following objects are masked from store_it() (pos = 5):
#   iris_df, x
```

What's the right way to do this? I'd like the user to just write `store_it()`. If `attach()` is the right way, how do I put it in the function so it doesn't keep making new environments? Please keep in mind the solution needs to pass CRAN's policies. Thanks in advance.

*Note: Someone will likely point out that I asked a similar question in the past. I made a new post because this question is more specific. [Package environment manipulation and submitting to CRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760473/package-environment-manipulation-and-submitting-to-cran)*

Answer (score 2):

**1)** CRAN will allow you to store and read back items in the tempdir as shown below or one could omit `tmpdir` and just use the current directory like R's `Rprof` does.

```
store_it <- function() {
    iris_df <- head(iris)
    rand <- runif(3)
    save(list = ls(), file = file.path(tempdir(), "store.rda"))
}

retrieve_it <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
    load(file.path(tempdir(), "store.rda"), envir = envir)
}
```

**2)** It is also possible to store objects in the package itself provided that the package defines an environment to hold them.  Thus this would work.

```
store <- new.env()

store_it2 <- function() {
    store$iris_df <- head(iris)
    store$rand <- runif(3)
    invisible(store)
}

retrieve_it2 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
    list2env(as.list(store), envir)
}
```

An alternative to `retrieve_it2` is to just export `store` in your package and then the user can access its contents as, for example, `store$x` or `with(store, x)` to access x or they can attach it using `attach(store)`.   Of course if `store` is exported then both could be provided -- the user can directly access `store` or they can run `retrieve_it2()` .

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. If I understand correctly, `retrieve_it()` would write to the global environment and has the chance of overwriting existing objects. From the feedback I had from the CRAN moderators, I don't think this is allowed.

Comment: `retrieve_it` loads the store into the environment specified by the `envir` argument which by default is the environment from which it is called but you can specify any environment you like. What it does is perfectly fine. Try putting it in a small package and run `R CMD check --as-cran`  and you will see it won't complain.

Comment: Have added a second approach as well. Either approach should work.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Ideally, it'd all happen in a single function. I put a better reprex here. Can you confirm if I'm using it correctly? https://gist.github.com/rjake/c709f0f699f5d4f037dfbb2eb7300783 I had an `envir` parameter that defaulted to `.GlobalEnv` in the function but it didn't pass when CRAN reviewed it. From what I can tell, R CMD Check isn't sensitive enough to catch the issue as it is looking specifically for `assign(..., .GlobalEnv)` Could you explain a little further why `parent.frame()` would be better than `.GlobalEnv`? The end result seems the same. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not running RStudio but just eyeballing it it looks ok.  `envir = parent.frame()`  is an idiom used by many R functions and seems flexible.  The user may not wish to muck up their global environment in the first place and this allows them to or not to.  I have added some more discussion at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```r
store_it <- local({
  .env <- NULL
  function() {
    if (is.null(.env)) .env <<- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
    .env$x <- runif(10)
    .env$iris_df <- head(iris)
    .env
  }
})
store_it()
# <environment: 0x0000000049340d80>
store_it()
# <environment: 0x0000000049340d80>
attach(store_it())
x
#  [1] 0.6478808 0.6862712 0.6969733 0.9513357 0.1560208 0.9332960 0.3966457
#  [8] 0.5067889 0.4244998 0.3747476
iris_df
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

detach()
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
# No traceback available
```

It will still "attach" the environment multiple times to your search path, because by calling `attach` repeatedly, that's what you're telling it to do.