# R Package Development - Global Variables vs Parameter

Tags: r

What would be the best practice when we would like to share variables across multiple sub-functions of same package (no need to update the content of those variables). e.g.

```
function1 <- function() {
  var1 <<- "x"
  var2 <<- "y"

  sub_function1()
  sub_function2()

}


sub_function1 <- function() {

  print(var1)

}

sub_function2 <- function() {

   print(var2)

}
```

Is it best practice to define global variables? I am just worried that if this package used in conjunction with other packages then global variables might interfere with each other.
Is it best practice to pass as parameters?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598242/global-variables-in-packages-in-r for some discussion of this. Personally I would say the best option is to use parameters.

Comment: Agree with @Marius; see in particular the answer by Paul Hiemstra which starts with *"In general global variables are **evil**. "* See also [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) for more details (it's a Python post but relevant to any language, as emphasised in the first answer).

Comment: thanks, that posts answer my question.