# Global variable on load in R package

Tags: r, unicode, package, dataset, cran

I'm writing a package in R and I'd like to include some sample objects in it that would be easily accessible for users to play with. The problem is they contain non-ASCII characters, and `R CMD check` won't allow this in .rda files in `data`. It will, however, allow Unicode in `inst/extdata`. I could just have these datasets read and wrapped in objects when the package is loaded. I tried `assign` and `<<-`, but I couldn't make either work.

Alternately, they could be loaded and saved as .rda files during the installation of the package. This would be preferable, in fact, but from what I read this seemed to be less possible.

Probably irrelevant but possibly interesting bit of history: I started the package on Debian unstable. I saved those datasets as .rda and they passed the check just fine. At one point I made a little correction, resaved them, and got a warning. I saved them again, and the warning disappeared. Then I moved to Debian stable, added some new datasets, resaved them all, and now I can't get rid of the warning in any way. When I save them from r-devel, however, I only get a note, not a warning.

Comment: Could you perhaps use a function instead? Have the function read from `extdata` and have the user load the object from the function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598242/global-variables-in-packages-in-r

Comment: Thank you so much! When you mentioned functions, I realized I was so intent on defining the variables as global I didn't think to simply export them through roxygen. I'm ashamed to say I spent two days on this, and I could have just asked you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is embarrassingly simple: read the data and prepare the variables in one of the files in the `R` folder, and `#' @export` them. No need to `assign` or anything.

Comment: Except R 4.0 or thereabouts introduces staged install which makes it impossible to use `system.file` for this. I ended up `dput`ting all the objects, pasting them into a file in the R folder, and escaping all the Unicode characters… which Windows doesn't know how to translate to native encoding. This is ridiculous.