# Altering internal data in R package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm working on a package (let's call it `myPackage`) that needs to refer to external data, which is too big to incorporate into the package itself (it's a lot of netCDF files).

Because of this I have an internal `PATH` variable (which I initiate in `/data-raw/`, which saves it to `sysdata.rda`, and I've turned off lazy loading). When asked to get data, any function can then use this PATH to find the data.

I want the user to be able to specify their path, so I wrote a function:

```
setpath<-function(path){
  myPackage:::PATH = path
}
```

Doing `setpath("C:/")` doesn't work. I get the error: Error in setpath("C:/") : object 'myPackage' not found.

I've also tried the following alternative function:

```
setpath<-function(path){
  PATH = path
}
```

This way, the variable `myPackage:::PATH` never changes.

How should I be doing this? Is internal data read-only?

Comment: It is possible to modify objects in another namespace (in this case `myPackage`) using `utils::assignInNamespace()`, but the documentation strongly discourages using it in production code. What you're asking is how to set a global variable, which is answered in [Global variables in packages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12598242) and [Global variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1236620). But the short answer is that it's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5526322). Instead add a `path` argument to all functions that need these files to keep them self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `options()`. Create an option with

`options(myPackageRepositoryPath = "some/path")`

and retrieve it

`path <- getOption(myPackageRepositoryPath)`

The same way as you set an option, you also can overwrite an option:

```
setpath<-function(path){
  options(myPackageRepositoryPath = path)
}
```

Comment: Do you know if internal data is read-only?