# How to view value of a variable inside a function?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General suggestions for debugging R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

When debugging, I would often like to know the value of a variable used in a function that has completed executing. How can that be achieved?

Example:

I have function:

```
MyFunction <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10) # assign 10 random normal numbers to x
    return(mean(x))
}
```

I would like to know the values stored in **x** which are not available to me after the function is done executing and the function's environment is cleaned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned debugging, so I assume the values are not needed later in the script, you just want to check what is happening. In that case, what I always do is use `browser`:

```
MyFunction <- function() {
    browser()
    x <- rnorm(10) # assign 10 random normal numbers to x
    return(mean(x))
}
```

This drops you into an interactive console inside the scope of the function, allowing you to inspect what is happening inside.

For general information about debugging in R I suggest [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r).

Comment: To avoid having to modify the code, you can also use `debug(MyFunction)` or `debugonce(MyFunction)`. But these will all interrupt execution as the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyFunction <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10) # assign 10 random normal numbers to x
    return(list(x,mean(x)))
}
```

This will return a list where the first element is x and the second is its mean

Comment: @Dmitrii If this works for you then I'd definitely go with this approach as it maintains the (safe) functional paradigm.

Comment: Sometimes x contains millions of entries and I do not want to have it returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options here.  The easiest is to use the `<<-` operator when you assign to `x`.  It's also the most likely to [get you into trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata).

```
> test <- function() x <- runif(1)
> x <- NA
> test()
> x
[1] NA
> test <- function() x <<- runif(1)
> test()
> x
[1] 0.7753325
```

**Edit**

@PaulHeimstra points out that you'd like this for debugging.  Here's a pointer to some general tricks:

[General suggestions for debugging in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

I'd recommend either setting `options(error=recover)` or using `trace()` in combination with `browser()`.

Comment: The OP states `when debugging`, so probably the OP wants have the value to check if things are going ok. I would use `browser` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some good solutions, I'd like to add one possibility. I emphasize on the fact that you want to  *know* the value of a variable used in a function *that has completed executing*.  So there is maybe no need to assign those values, and you don't want (a priori) to stop execution. The solution is to simply use `print`. So it is not used by default but only when you want to debug, the option to print or not can be passed as a function argument:

```
MyFunction <- function(x, y, verbose = FALSE) {
    a <- x * y
    if (verbose) print(a)
    b <- x - y
    if (verbose) print(b)
    return(a * b)
}
```

In general, you would run your function like this: `MyFunction(10, 4)` but when you want to see those intermediate results, do `MyFunction(10, 4, verbose = TRUE)`.

Comment: I use this already often, however sometimes my vectors have million entries...

Comment: You don't have to print the whole object, you can print its `str`, `head`, `summary`, `length`, `mean`, etc.