# Counter in an if/else statement using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, counter

I am relatively new to R and programming in general and I was wondering if there is a way to put a counter inside of an if else statement in my for loop. I have the following if/else statement inside of a for loop:

```
if(runif(1)<min(1,r)) {
Gibbsalph[,t]=alphcandidate
} else{
Gibbsalph[,t]=Gibbsalph[,t-1]
}
```

Is there a way to count how many times the loop chose the "if" option (i.e. how many times Gibbsalph[,t]=alphcandidate) while proceeding through the iterations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be useful as it avoids creating the global variable i. see [Examples of the perils of globals in R and Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata)

```
init.counter <- function(){
  x <- 0
  function(){
    x <<- x + 1
    x
   }
}  #source: hadley wickham

> counter1 <- init.counter()
> 
> counter1()
[1] 1
> counter1()
[1] 2
>
```

To access the value of the counter without iterating it:

```
environment(counter1)$x
```

So it would end up as:

```
counter2 <- init.counter()
if(runif(1)<min(1,r)) {
counter2()
Gibbsalph[,t]=alphcandidate
} else{
Gibbsalph[,t]=Gibbsalph[,t-1]
}
environment(counter2)$x
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up, this is excellent. The link you posted was helpful to me as well. I will definitely take that into account as I do my further programming!

Comment: Nice use of a lexical closure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you've got now:

```
if(runif(1)<min(1,r))
```

Assuming your loop is over the sequence `jj = 1:t` , how about:

```
alltests <- runif(t) < min(1,r)  #vector of TRUE, FALSE
wincount <- sum(alltests)
```

and inside the loop,

```
Gibbsalph[,t] <- alphcandidate * alltests[jj] + Gibbsalph[,t-1]*(!alltests[jj])
```