# Making table of non-regression estimates in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm performing decomposition analysis of socioeconomic inequality of health, and have gotten the code down, generally following the World Bank procedure. Here's the relevant part of my code.

```
foreach x of global X {
qui {
    sca b_`x' = _b[`x']
    corr rank `x' [aw=newweight], c
    sca cov_`x' = r(cov_12)
    sum `x' [aw=newweight]
    sca elas_`x' = (b_`x'*r(mean))/avg
    sca CI_`x' = 2*cov_`x'/r(mean)
    sca con_`x' = elas_`x'*CI_`x'
    sca prcnt_`x' = con_`x'/c
    }
di "`x' elasticity:", elas_`x'
di "`x' concentration index:", CI_`x'
di "`x' contribution:", con_`x'
di "`x' percentage contribution:", prcnt_`x'
}
```

Now, what I want is these final four estimates to be able to be displayed for all of my variables x in X, similar to four regression tables appended together with their coefficients. I am struggling to find how to properly "save" these estimates and call them up in `esttab`, `tabout`, `table`, etc. I merely display the original regression coefficients.

Comment: Your `avg` is undefined in this code. Also, it is unclear where `_b[whatever]` is coming from.

Comment: Note for beginners: This code is incomplete and won't run as such,

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach x of global X {
    qui {
        sca b_`x' = _b[`x']
        corr rank `x' [aw=newweight], c
        sca cov_`x' = r(cov_12)
        sum `x' [aw=newweight], meanonly
        sca elas_`x' = (b_`x'*r(mean))/avg
        sca CI_`x' = 2*cov_`x'/r(mean)
        sca con_`x' = elas_`x'*CI_`x'
        sca prcnt_`x' = con_`x'/c
    }
    di "`x' elasticity:", elas_`x'
    di "`x' concentration index:", CI_`x'
    di "`x' contribution:", con_`x'
    di "`x' percentage contribution:", prcnt_`x'
    matrix results = nullmat(results) \ ///
                     ( elas_`x', CI_`x', con_`x', prcnt_`x')
}
matrix rownames results = $X
matrix colnames results = elasticity concentration_index ///
                          contribution percentage_contribution
```

Now you can feed the matrix `results` to whatever output program in Stata you may wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with `nlcom, post` that can produce the proper `e(b)` and `e(V)` matrices that estimation formatting command such as `estout` can pick up. Something along the lines of

```
gen rank_n = rank / _N
gen rank_sq = rank_n * rank_n
foreach x of global X {
    gen cross_rank_`x' = rank_n * `x'
    gen `x'_sq = `x' * `x'

    svy : mean `x' `x'_sq rank_n rank_sq cross_rank_`x'

    nlcom ///
       (corr: (_b[cross_rank_`x']-_b[`x']*_b[rank_n]) ///
          /sqrt( (_b[`x'_sq]-_b[`x']*_b[`x'])*(_b[rank_sq]-_b[rank_n]*_b[rank_n]) ) ///
       (concentration: 2*(_b[cross_rank_`x']-_b[`x']*_b[rank_n]) / _b[`x'] )

    estout /*the way you like it*/
}
```

Since, as I noted in the comment, I can't tell where `_b[x]` is coming from, I am not sure how to wrap it into the `mean` and `nlcom`.

Also note that [the use of globals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6917172/874882) is the biggest thing in Stata... at least according to the votes on SO :).