# Dynamically assign variable and file names

Tags: r

I want to rename the variables by appending a suffix (".", followed by `variable_suffix`).
The file names should be "_" delimited and contain both `var_names` and `subtype_value`.

```
subtypes <- unique(clin.info$type)

for (subtype_value in subtypes) {

  ...

  # Append subtype_value to all the output variable names
  variable_suffix <- paste0(".", subtype_value)

  # Modify variable names
  assign(paste0("pathway.activities", variable_suffix), pathway.activities)
  assign(paste0("cell.fractions", variable_suffix), cell.fractions)
  assign(paste0("tf.activities", variable_suffix), tf.activities)
  assign(paste0("lrpair.weights", variable_suffix), lrpair.weights)
  assign(paste0("ccpair.scores", variable_suffix), ccpair.scores)
  assign(paste0("patient.ICBresponse", variable_suffix), patient.ICBresponse)
  
  # Get the variable names with the specified pattern
  var_names <- ls(pattern = "pathway.activities|cell.fractions|tf.activities|lrpair.weights|ccpair.scores|patient.ICBresponse")
  
  # Save files with a more descriptive naming convention
  save(list = mget(var_names),
       file = file.path(paste0(gsub("\\.", "_", var_names, fixed = TRUE), "_KIRP_", subtype_value, ".rda")))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid first argument
```

Input:

```
> unique(clin.info$type)
[1] 1 2
```

Expected output:

```
File names:

    "pathway_activities_KIRP_1.rda"
    "pathway_activities_KIRP_2.rda"
    "cell_fractions_KIRP_1.rda"
    "cell_fractions_KIRP_2.rda"

Variable names:
pathway.activities.1
pathway.activities.2
cell.fractions.1
cell.fractions.2
```

Comment: Errors aside, your codes assigns the same existing object, e. g. `pathway.activities` to at least two new "subtype" objects `pathway.activities.1` and `pathway.activities.2` (which are then saved). Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Some (more) problems: (1) `gsub("\\.", ..., fixed=TRUE)` is double-fixing the problem, which means it won't work. Use either escaped-dot `"\\."` without `fixed=`, or use `"."` with `fixed=TRUE`. (2) `file.path(.)` with a single argument is a no-op, a waste. The only time it does anything is when there are two or more arguments. (3) Where exactly does the error occur? This question is not reproducible, so just parsing through the code is not clear.

Comment: Speaking from experience and from many people's online advice, it is generally bad practice in R (or any other programming language) to save data into the name of variables in the global environment. Totally can be done, but in most cases results in code that is more of a pain to maintain and debug than if you store data otherwise (e.g. in a list or a data frame). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata