# How to pass parameters by reference in R?

Tags: r

I want to pass a matrix into a function and save its modifying within function, how can I pass it by reference like C++ or java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/r-pass-by-reference  ...

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
?ReferenceClasses
```

The below is a hack that could cause a lot of confusion:

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
    name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    x <- x + 1
    assign(name, x, envir=parent.frame())
    return(invisible())
}
```

Comment: how is this different than the other answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval.parent` and `substitute`.

```
> my_fun <- function(x, value){
+     eval.parent(substitute(x<-value))
+ }

> k = 1
> my_fun(k, 100)
> k
[1] 100
```