# how to rename multiple df that in the environment at once

Tags: r

If I have a list of dfs in my environment, and I would like to rename them base on a mapping file I created, how can I do that?

my mapping file is looks like this:

```
mapping<- structure(list(Tab = c("Study", "Score", "Level", "Level2", 
"Level3", "level_Grouped"), DatasetName = c("Output3", "Output4", 
"Output5", "Output6", "Output7", "Output3.g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am thinking to get the output in the list first, then loop through the rename process. but I kind of lost in the process. what should I use for rename a df? Could anyone guide me on this?

```
output_list<-ls(pattern="^Output")
lapply(output_list, function(x)...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Almost always, the answer to this is "if you have a list of data frames, then you should put them in an actual list object". This stops you having to do ugly and dangerous things with `get()` and `assign()`. You just do `names(my_list_of_dfs) <- ...` and rename them however you want. Of course this may not be possible in your case. If so, `get()` and `assign()` are indeed your friends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible because you cannot rename `data.frame` in R.
More info here: [How can I change the name of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225715/how-can-i-change-the-name-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: is it a way that I can reach the goal of `mapping$Tab` <- `mapping$DatasetName` without manually write it one by one?

Comment: Maybe with a workaround but I'm not sure. I tried some things but didn't manage to do what you want