# Function that returns changed data

Tags: r

I have a function

```
Trace.repair(dat, row.names)
```

While performing this function i change values in my table dat.  Is there a way to update dat without doing the obvious

```
dat<-Trace.repair(dat, row.names){blah; blah; print(dat)}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/r-pass-by-reference

Comment: Can you make your a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

use `assign`.  Something like this:

```
Trace.repair <- function(x) {
     # do tricks with x
  assign("dat", x, envir=parent.frame())
}
```

This assumes that you always want to change variable "dat" in your calling environment.  If you want the outcome to be assigned to the variable with the same name as you call it, like `Trace.repair(another_dat)`, you can recover the variable name by `as.character(sys.call()[2])` and replace `"dat"` in the code with that:

```
Trace.repair <- function(x) {
     # do tricks with x
   assign(as.character(sys.call()[2]), x, envir=parent.frame())
}
```

However, if you don't call it with explicit variable name but with something like `Trace.repair(-dat)`, then you get a variable named "-dat" in your environment.

Comment: my dat is also a list.  So i am actually working with dat$bin

Comment: Can you give an example what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you tell me what is going on with 'sys.call' , and 'parent.frame'?  When i call sys.call()[2], on the command line, all i get is NULL.  But it works well for my functions where the only input is a dataframe, and not a dataframe from a list of dataframes.

Comment: `sys.call()` gives the list of arguments about how the function was called.  The first one is the function name, the next one the first argument, and so on.  If you call it just in command line, it is not inside of any function and I don't know what it does then.  `envir` tells which environment you want to use.  `parent.frame` is where the function was called from, `.GlobalEnv` is the common workspace.  If you want your variable to sit in the workspace, then you probably can ignore that argument.  But just try, use `browser()` command inside of your function and test :-)