# Decreasing memory consumption in R -- pass by reference / data.table

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

I've already achieved a substantial speed up (~6.5x) by moving subsetting operations from base `data.frame` operations to `data.table` operations. But I'm wondering if I can get any improvement in memory.

My understanding is that R does **not** natively pass-by-reference (eg. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/r-pass-by-reference)). So, I'm seeking a method (short of re-writing a complex function in `Rcpp`) to do so. `data.table` provides some improvement [**after editing my question to include typo caught by @joshua ulrich below**]. But I'm looking for a larger improvement if possible.

- Another option is possibly the [R.oo package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.oo/R.oo.pdf), though I haven't yet found a good tutorial. (*I still need to read [this](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/Conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/Bengtsson.pdf).*
- Would [reference classes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/refClass.html) help at all?

*In my actual use case, I'm doing simulation in parallel of numerous datasets with optimization via simulated annealing. I'd rather not re-write both simulated annealing and my loss function calculations in Rcpp due to the increased dev time and increased [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).*

#### Example of problem:

What I'm largely concerned with is removing some subset of observations from a dataset and adding in another subset of observations. A very simple (nonsensical) example is given here. Is there a way to decrease memory usage? My current usage appears to pass-by-value and therefore memory usage (RAM) is roughly doubled.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(444L)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))
df2 <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))

prof_func <- function(df) {
  s1 <- sample(1:nrow(df), size= 500, replace=F)
  s2 <- sample(1:nrow(df), size= 500, replace=F)
  return(rbind(df[-s1,], df[s2,]))
}

dt_m <- df_m <- vector("numeric", length= 500L)

for (i in 1:500) {

  Rprof("./DF_mem.out", memory.profiling = TRUE)
  y <- prof_func(df1)
  Rprof(NULL)
  df <- summaryRprof("./DF_mem.out", memory= "both")
  df_m[i] <- df$by.self$mem.total[which(rownames(df$by.self) == "\"rbind\"")]


  Rprof("./DT_mem.out", memory.profiling = TRUE)
  y2 <- prof_func(df2)
  Rprof(NULL)
  dt <- summaryRprof("./DT_mem.out", memory = "both")
  dt_m[i] <- dt$by.self$mem.total[which(rownames(dt$by.self) == "\"rbind\"")]

}
pryr::object_size(df1)
80 MB
pryr::object_size(df2)
80 MB

# EDITED: via typo / fix from @Joshua Ulrich.
# improvement in memory usage via DT. still not pass-by-reference
quantile(df_m, seq(0,1,.1))
    0%    10%    20%    30%    40%    50%    60%    70%    80%    90%   100% 
379.00 428.60 440.10 447.70 455.36 459.20 466.48 469.89 474.40 482.10 512.60 
quantile(dt_m, seq(0,1,.1))
    0%    10%    20%    30%    40%    50%    60%    70%    80%    90%   100% 
 76.80  84.50  84.50  92.10  92.10  92.10  92.10 107.30 116.46 130.20 157.00
```

#### Appendix:

```
### speed improvement:
#-----------------------------------------------
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(444L)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))
df2 <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))

microbenchmark(
  df= {
    s1 <- sample(1:nrow(df1), size= 500, replace=F)
    s2 <- sample(1:nrow(df1), size= 500, replace=F)
    df1 <- rbind(df1[-s1,], df1[s2,])
  },
  dt= {
    s1 <- sample(1:nrow(df2), size= 500, replace=F)
    s2 <- sample(1:nrow(df2), size= 500, replace=F)
    df2 <- rbind(df2[-s1,], df2[s2,])

  }, times= 100L)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   df 672.5106 757.65188 814.1582 809.6346 864.6668 998.2290   100   b
   dt  68.1254  85.73178 139.1256 120.3613 148.8243 397.7359   100  a
```

Comment: I don't think there's much point to including the sample calls inside your benchmark, since they're shared. For the `rbind` thing, I guess you might save speed by rearranging the vector of row numbers and subsetting once rather than using `rbind`. `myrows = df2[, c(.I[-s1], .I[s2])]; df2[myrows]` or similar. By the way, regarding pass by reference, this may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15759117/1191259 Finally, if your true application uses `sample` like this, you should consider switching to `sample.int` or at least writing `n` instead of `1:n` as the first arg.

Comment: @Symbolix `rbindlist` is called by method dispatch automatically... rerunning `Rprof` now w/o the typo that Joshua Ulrich identified below

Comment: @Frank thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Alex - so it does! thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Perhaps also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table) for adding/removing rows (more-or-less) by reference. a bit convoluted though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prof_func` has an error. It calls `rbind` on `df1` instead of it's argument (`df`). Fix that, and you will see reduced memory usage with the data.table object.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(444L)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))
df2 <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol= 10))

prof_func <- function(df) {
  s1 <- sample(1:nrow(df), size= 500, replace=F)
  s2 <- sample(1:nrow(df), size= 500, replace=F)
  return(rbind(df[-s1,], df[s2,]))
}

dt_m <- df_m <- vector("numeric", length= 500L)

for (i in 1:100) {
  Rprof("./DF_mem.out", memory.profiling = TRUE, interval=0.01)
  y <- prof_func(df1)
  Rprof(NULL)
  df <- summaryRprof("./DF_mem.out", memory= "both")
  df_m[i] <- df$by.total["\"rbind\"","mem.total"]

  Rprof("./DT_mem.out", memory.profiling = TRUE, interval=0.01)
  y2 <- prof_func(df2)
  Rprof(NULL)
  dt <- summaryRprof("./DT_mem.out", memory = "both")
  dt_m[i] <- dt$by.total["\"rbind\"","mem.total"]
}
quantile(df_m, seq(0,1,.1))
#    0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
#   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 413.4 432.5 455.0 485.9 
quantile(dt_m, seq(0,1,.1))
#    0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
#   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  53.9  84.5 122.6 153.1
```

Comment: Well, that's a mightily annoying typo... thanks. Though I don't have the typo in my real problem, so still looking for pass-by-reference if possible

Comment: @Alex: then you need to rework your example to better illustrate your actual problem, since your example currently does what you're asking for.

Comment: the memory overhead comes in computation, not post garbage collection... if you have any thought's I'd be glad to hear them in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I agree-- trying to think through that now... I'm going to accept your answer to this and see if I can come up with a better example in a separate question.