# Create list of reference to others objects in R

Tags: r, reference

Probably this question is already answered but I'm not sure if it was exactly the same kind of answer I want. I search here and in other sites but neither as useful to me.

I'd like to understand how to create a variable with a reference to another in R.

Like:

Imagine I have this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

Now, I know I may do this:

```
c <- list(
    var.a = list( 
        description = "this is var.a",
        data = a ),
    var.b = list( 
        description = "this is var.b",
        data = b ) )
```

The code above didn't create a reference. Because If I do:

```
c$data$a[2] <- 99
```

See what I got:

```
c$data$a
# 1 99 3 4 5
a
# 1 2 3 4 5
```

So, what I'd like to have is somehow got this behavior below:

```
c$data$a[2] <- 99
c$data$a
# 1 99 3 4 5
a
# 1 99 3 4 5
```

Maybe this is a very silly simple question but any help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is possible in `R`. Now I am curious to know too

Comment: Related and relevant: [Can you pass-by-reference in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/can-you-pass-by-reference-in-r); from the first answer to that post: "*Objects in assignment statements are immutable. R will copy the object not just the reference.*"

Comment: But also check reference classes, as mentioned in one of the answers from the question linked by Maurits.

Comment: I saw this question @MauritsEvers mentioned as I saw others sites too. Reference classes seems quiet noise, if I would like to modify constantily, but S4 (which I need to study a little more) seems solve part of the problem. I don't understand why R choose this behavior.

Comment: The use of `environment`s allow pass-by-reference without ref-classes or other complexities. (If I remember correctly, ref-classes use environments for this purpose and others.)

Comment: if you're working with `data.frame`, say, you could switch to `data.table` and when you set `dt <- df`, then `dt` 'refers' to df and is not a copy. Not sure if that exists for other R data types