# Problems with an implementation of Heapsort algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, heapsort

I would like to create my own Heapsort algorithm in R.
That is my code

```
heapify <- function(array, n, i)
{
  parent <- i
  leftChild <- 2 * i + 1
  rightChild <- 2 * i + 2

  if ((leftChild < n) & (array[parent] < array[leftChild]))
  {
    parent = leftChild
  }

  if ((rightChild < n) & (array[parent] < array[rightChild]))
  {
    parent = rightChild
  }

  if (parent != i)
  {
    array = replace(array, c(i, parent), c(array[parent], array[i]))
    heapify(array, n, parent)
  }
}

heapSort <- function(array)
{
  n <- length(array)

  for (i in (n+1):1)
  {
    heapify(array, n, i)
  }

  for (i in n:1)
  {
    array = replace(array, c(i, 0), c(array[0], array[i]))
    heapify(array, i, 1)
  }
  print(array)
}
```

However that implementation seems to be incorrect. That's an example of an input and output.

```
array <- c(5, 14, 3, 70, 64)
heapSort(array)

Output: [1]  5 14  3 70 64
```

I have spent quite a while and I have no idea where the problem is. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you were trying to convert the algorithm posted on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/) where they implement this in many zero based languages. This is one of the sources of your problem (R starts indexing at 1 instead of 0).

### Base Zero Indexing Issues:

Example 1:

```
                         ## We also need to swap these indices
array = replace(array, c(i, 0), c(array[0], array[i]))
heapify(array, i, 1)

Should be:

array <- replace(array, c(i, 1), array[c(1, i)])
array <- heapify(array, i, 1)
```

Example 2:

```
leftChild <- 2 * i + 1
rightChild <- 2 * i + 2

Should be:

leftChild <- 2 * (i - 1) + 1
rightChild <- 2 * (i - 1) + 2
```

### Pass By Reference Assumption

In R, you cannot pass an object by reference (see this question and answers [Can you pass-by-reference in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2603184/4408538)). This means that when we call a recursive function we must assign it and the recursive function must return something.

In `heapify` we must return `array`. Also every call to `heapify` we must assign `array` to the output.

Here is the amended code:

```
heapify <- function(array, n, i)
{
    parent <- i
    leftChild <- 2 * (i - 1) + 1
    rightChild <- 2 * (i - 1) + 2

    if ((leftChild < n) & (array[parent] < array[leftChild]))
    {
        parent <- leftChild
    }

    if ((rightChild < n) & (array[parent] < array[rightChild]))
    {
        parent <- rightChild
    }

    if (parent != i) {
        array <- replace(array, c(i, parent), array[c(parent, i)])
        array <- heapify(array, n, parent)
    }

    array
}

heapSort <- function(array)
{
    n <- length(array)

    for (i in floor(n / 2):1) {
        array <- heapify(array, n, i)
    }

    for (i in n:1) {
        array <- replace(array, c(i, 1), array[c(1, i)])
        array <- heapify(array, i, 1)
    }

    array
}
```

Here are some tests (note this algorithm is extremely inefficient in R.. do not try on vectors much larger than below):

```
array <- c(5, 14, 3, 70, 64)
heapSort(array)
[1]  3  5 14 64 70

set.seed(11)
largerExample <- sample(1e3)

head(largerExample)
[1] 278   1 510  15  65 951

identical(heapSort(largerExample), 1:1e3)
[1] TRUE
```