# How to get the name of the current environment THIS within a function

Tags: r, oop, parameters, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

It looks like you can have one function pass data back transparently to a parent function with the `assign` operation.

### Example (Setup)

```
calling = function()
    {
    a = 25;
    cat("\n ...CALLING... a = ", a, "\n");
    assign("a", a, envir=parent.frame(1) );  # ?sys.calls
    }


caller = function()
    {
    a = 15;
    cat("\n ...CALLER... a = ", a, "\n");
    
    pf = parent.frame(); ## how to say THIS current FRAME
    cat("\n ...CALLER_FRAME... pf = \n");
    print(pf);
    
    cat("\n\n\n");
    
    calling();
    cat("\n ...CALLER*... a = ", a, "\n");
    }
```

### RUN

```
a = 5;
cat("\n ...GLOBAL... a = ", a, "\n");
caller();
# scope, should mess with GLOBAL = 5
cat("\n ...GLOBAL*... a = ", a, "\n");
```

### OUTPUT

```
> a = 5;
> cat("\n ...GLOBAL... a = ", a, "\n");

 ...GLOBAL... a =  5 
> caller();

 ...CALLER... a =  15 

 ...CALLER_FRAME... pf = 
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>




 ...CALLING... a =  25 

 ...CALLER*... a =  25 
> # scope, should mess with GLOBAL = 5
> cat("\n ...GLOBAL*... a = ", a, "\n");

 ...GLOBAL*... a =  5
```

## Question

So above, the GLOBAL `a` was not altered, but `calling` was able to update the value of `a` for `caller` without returning the value.  That is, `calling` passed back the value to `caller` with `assign`.

The question is in the code, in `caller`, how do I get **THIS** current frame reference?

How could I use that if I had more complicated nesting?  Pass `envir` to `calling` that may have been a few functions deep?  This reference [Can you pass-by-reference in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/) has some discussion, but I don't fully under **THIS** current frame reference of `caller`?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the current environment? `environment()` with no arguments will return the current environment. If that’s not what you want, can you clarify you question by providing expected output?

Comment: R is not C, in `instruction;` the semi-colon is the instruction separator. `instruction;` is *two* instructions, `instruction; NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zephryl said, `environment()` returns the currently active environment.  You could write your `calling()` function like this:

```r
calling <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  a <- 25
  assign("a", a, envir = envir)
}
```

and then it would by default assign in the caller, but if you specified the `envir` argument it could assign there instead.

Then you could do something like this:

```r
myenv <- new.env()
calling(envir = myenv)
myenv$a
#> [1] 25
```

to do the assignment in a custom environment.  And if you wrote `caller()` like this:

```r
caller <- function() {
  a <- 2
  calling(envir = environment())
  cat("in caller, a=", a, "\n")
}
a <- 1
caller()
#> in caller, a= 25
print(a)
#> [1] 1
```

it would work just like

```r
caller2 <- function() {
  a <- 3
  calling()
  cat("in caller2, a=", a, "\n")
}

a <- 4
caller2()
#> in caller2, a= 25
print(a)
#> [1] 4
```

because while evaluating `caller()`, `environment()` gives a reference to the active environment, and while evaluating `calling()`, `parent.frame()` points to the environment of the caller, which would be the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to avoid create a new env, one to build on the base.  So `environment()` and `parent.frame(1)` and `parent.frame()` are all the same thing?

Comment: No.  The last two are the same, but `environment()` is different.  It just happens to give the same value as `parent.frame()` in the context described.